# Code does not recognise updated cells that are prior to the cell performing the action

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA, but the below is nothing special or complex.

I have a typical worksheet vba code that formats cells dependent on the value of another. The issue I have, and unable to find an answer for by searching, is cells updated by the code that are prior to the cell initiating the change, are not recognised and so formatted. Another update (could be a simple enter in a blank cell) has to be performed for the code to fire again and so recognise the cells have changed.

If I update Cell A72 in the code below, the text appears in cells A70 and A71, but this change is not recognised at the time and the formatting is not performed. Cell A73 is also updated and the formatting is performed as expected.

I have used the typical settings for faster code processing and I am aware that the EnableEvents is the culprit or the one stopping the code recognising the cells it has just updated at the time of running.

If I take out the settings that speed up the process and endure the 10 seconds of wait, all the cells populate and format as expected.

What I cannot find the answer to, with the faster update settings in place, is how to make the process re-appraise the sheet for all the updated cells and not just those below where the initiation took place.

Thanks in advance...

Code...

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
  Select Case Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70").Value
         Case "X"
             Sheets("Inbound Only").Tab.Color = vbGreen
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:A73").Value = "N/A"
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B70:I70").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Case "N/A"
            Sheets("Inbound Only").Tab.Color = vbBlack
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Strikethrough = True
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Italic = True
         Case ""
             Sheets("Inbound Only").Tab.Color = vbBlack
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Strikethrough = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Italic = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B70:I70").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End Select
  Select Case Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71").Value
         Case "X"
             Sheets("Outbound Only").Tab.Color = vbGreen
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70,A72:A73").Value = "N/A"
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B71:I71").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Case "N/A"
            Sheets("Outbound Only").Tab.Color = vbBlack
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Font.Strikethrough = True
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Font.Italic = True
         Case ""
             Sheets("Outbound Only").Tab.Color = vbBlack
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Font.Strikethrough = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:I71").Font.Italic = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B71:I71").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End Select
  Select Case Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72").Value
         Case "X"
             Sheets("Inbound & Outbound").Tab.Color = vbGreen
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:A71,A73").Value = "N/A"
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B72:I72").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Case "N/A"
            Sheets("Inbound & Outbound").Tab.Color = vbBlack
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Font.Strikethrough = True
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Font.Italic = True
         Case ""
             Sheets("Inbound & Outbound").Tab.Color = vbBlack
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Font.Strikethrough = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A72:I72").Font.Italic = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B72:I72").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End Select
  Select Case Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73").Value
         Case "X"
             Sheets("Company Internal").Tab.Color = vbGreen
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:A72").Value = "N/A"
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B73:I73").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Case "N/A"
            Sheets("Company Internal").Tab.Color = vbBlack
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Font.Strikethrough = True
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Font.Italic = True
         Case ""
             Sheets("Company Internal").Tab.Color = vbBlack
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Font.Strikethrough = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A73:I73").Font.Italic = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B73:I73").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End Select
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you update `A72` the code for the formatting of `A70:A71` is already run through, but the code for formatting `A73` is still coming below. That is why the last one is formatted but the first 2 not. I would use conditional formatting for that and let the code only handle the tab color and value changes.

Comment: Thank you Peh,  but if i run this without the Application.EnableEvents = False setting (used to speed up the code processing), everything works as it should and the cells are formatted at the same time. I am hoping there is a way I can force this action with the setting in place. Also, this is just a snippet of the code that is affected, I have removed the remainder for clarity and so the processing speed settings would be beneficial if possible.

Comment: I think what i really need here is to have the EnableEvents set but get the code to ignore the range of cells being formatted as to stop triggering another run each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable and disable events to avoid recursive update. I did not dig much into your code but you can enable and disable the applation events for the specific part of your code desired.
Below what could be an example. Might not specifically applying to your case but for you to get the idea:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Select Case Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70").Value
         Case "X"
             Sheets("Inbound Only").Tab.Color = vbGreen
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A71:A73").Value = "N/A"
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B70:I70").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Case "N/A"
            Sheets("Inbound Only").Tab.Color = vbBlack
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Strikethrough = True
            Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Italic = True
         Case ""
             Sheets("Inbound Only").Tab.Color = vbBlack
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Strikethrough = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("A70:I70").Font.Italic = False
             Sheets("Project Information").Range("B70:I70").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End Select
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Comment: Hi rustyBucketBay and thanks for your time and the suggestion. I had tried this in the CASE X section, enabling it before setting the other cells to 'N/A' and then switching it off, but the results are as if you had never turned it off in the first place and a slow run. I have mentioned above in a comment to Peh that I think the only way around it is going  to be stopping the code monitoring a range of cells and so not registering the formatting updates being applied.